# Mod Rewrite not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written a simple mod rewrite script to turn `website.com/index.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3` into `website.com/index/1/2/3`. For some reason it's not working, any ideas why?

```
#RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1\.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ comments.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

Answer (score 1):

- The first rule rewrites `index/1/2/3` to `index/1/2/3.php`.
- then the second rule rewrites this to `index.php/index/1/2/3.php`
- and finally the last rule doesn't match.

If you want to rewrite `website.com/index.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3` into `website.com/index/1/2/3`, you must capture the query string arguments with [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and insert them into a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} var1=(.*?)&var2=(.*?)&var3=(.*?)
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index/%1/%2/%3 [L]
```

If you want to redirect instead of internally rewrite, i.e. show the new URL in the browser, use `[R,L]` as RewriteRule flags

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index/%1/%2/%3 [R,L]
```

Comment: +1 this actually answers the question "why doesn't this work".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the rewrite on line 6 will catch that and send it to index.php.  It's hard to tell not knowing what things are files and directories, but I would guess that it isn't.  If you have access to the httpd.conf you can turn up the rewrite logging, set

```
RewriteLogLevel 8
```

And it will log far more information than you need to debug this.  On newer versions of apache  the setting is set with LogLevel e.g..

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8
```

which may be allowed in vhosts or htaccess so look it up in your version's docs.

Don't leave this on as it will seriously impact performance.